# Permissions On Folder Give Me Access Denied. Why?

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, file-permissions, file-sharing, server-message-block

I have a user (dAdmin) and that user is a member of the domain admin's group and is also a member of the local server's (serverA) Administrators group.

On the folder (fShare) I set it up as a share in a cluster.  I give FULL rights to the domain admins group and the local server's (serverA) group called Administrators.

For some reason when I try to access the folder as the current user (dAdmin) I get access denied!  I can click the OK button on get perm access and get in just fine.  When I do that though it adds my user account (dAdmin) to the ACLs!!!

[image]

What's the point of groups if Windows will not use them?  I have a user added to a group, that group has full access to the folder, then bam!  Access Denied!!!

Why does this happen?  Why can't I rely on the groups for access instead of the individual user accounts??

Thanks!

Comment: possible typo, 3rd para `(sAdmin)` maybe should be `(dAdmin)`?

Comment: It's a sort of easter egg from microsoft telling you why you shouldn't be using windows

Comment: In the past setting group permissions in `AD`, sometimes the user had to log out out and in again for some group settings to be applied, as certain `AD` settings are only applied on login. Though your situation sounds different there may be some connection

Comment: @gwillie - Tried that first thing because that's exactly what happens.  The GP only applies when a user logs on.  So if you add a user to a group after they are logged on it will have NO effect until they refresh their policies via "gpupdate /force" or logoff then back on.  But that was not the problem.  I added the user to the group long ago with many logons since.  But...  Just for the heck of it I went ahead and REBOOTED altogether just to rule out anything I forgot about.

Comment: I think it has to do with the new way Administrator privileges are handled.  Kind of like when you run a program even though you're an Administrator you run it WITHOUT Admin privileges.  Though you can right click and "Run as Administrator".  Maybe even though I'm a member of the admin group I do not have those rights.  I guess it's time to create a NEW security group in my domain and deal with rights that way instead of depending on the Administrators group by default.  ;)

Answer (score -1):

There is a tool called [BeOwner](http://forgedsoft.com/BeOwner-Mass-file-permission-reset-tool) that can take ownership to all folders and files at once:

[image]